# How do I actually use Authorization Services?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, macos

I've been searching and experimenting for nearly four hours now, so I'm gonna just ask straight up:

How can I correctly use the [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges) API to show the user a system-level authorization window, the same one you see when you click a lock icon in System Preferences?

From what I can tell, there is no way to do it using Cocoa if you want to do it programmatically, and if your goal is to call an executable that normally needs to be called via `sudo` (in my case, `/usr/bin/pmset`) you're up a creek without a paddle.

I challenge you, I implore you: Please, enlighten me.

Thank you. :)

Comment: You linked to the documentation. You need to create the authorization first, but the API takes care of prompting the user for the password and such.

Comment: Yes, I know. I can't make heads or tails of it. Any possibility of posting or linking to a working code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/invoking-other-processes-in-cocoa.html
- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/BetterAuthorizationSample/index.html

Comment: Thanks! The first link had just what I needed in the sample project.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you should do real error handling and such, but here is an example to get you started.

```
AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;
OSStatus err;
err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL,
            NULL, 
            kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights|kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed,
            &auth);
if( err != errAuthorizationSuccess ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "oops: %ld\n", (long int)err);
    exit(-1);
}
char *opts[] = { "some", "parameters", "to", "pm", NULL };
err = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(
    auth,
    "/usr/bin/pmset",
    kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,
    opts,
    NULL);
AuthorizationFree(auth, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults);
if( err != errAuthorizationSuccess ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "oops: %ld\n", (long int)err);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: I am getting linker errors when I call these authorization functions. Any idea why?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian You need to add the appropriate frameworks to your project. I believe these are all in the security framework. There have been a lot of changes to that framework in Lion, so some of this may or may not still be available or may have moved to another framework.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. Funny enough the auto-completion works without the addition of any frameworks in Cocoa.

Comment: AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is deprecated... Any alternate way to execute with higher priveledges ?.